# Formal definition of interval

Tags: real-analysis

My Real Analysis class hasn't given me a satisfying definition for when $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval. Even in my textbook "Understanding Analysis" by Abbott, it says $I$ is an interval if $I=(a,b)$ or $I=[a,b]$ and alike.

My question is, can I use the following definition for an intervals:

> $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval when for any $a,b\in I$, if $a < b$, then $(a,b) \subseteq I$
> ?

Comment: The definition at end of your post is more general. The surprising part about this definition is when we apply same definition on $\mathbb{Q} $ instead of $\mathbb{R} $ and then we have the possibility that an interval of rationals may not have end points. An interval of reals on the other hand has end points and thus one can replace the definition with an exhaustive list of various types of intervals based on the nature of endpoints and their inclusion in the interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an exercise for you, that I give to my real analysis class, as one of the first exercises after the completeness axiom:

> Given a subset $I \subset \mathbb R$, to say that $I$ is an *interval* means that $I$ has at least 2 points, and for all $x<y<z \in \mathbb R$, if $x,z \in I$ then $y \in I$. Prove that if $I$ is an interval then $I$ has one of the following forms, for some $a < b \in \mathbb R$:
> $$(a,b) \qquad (a,b] \qquad (a,+\infty)
> $$
> $$[a,b) \qquad [a,b] \qquad [a,+\infty)
> $$
> $$(-\infty,b) \qquad (\infty,b] \qquad \underbrace{(-\infty,+\infty)}_{= \, \mathbb R}
> $$

Of course each of these intervals has to be defined in the standard manner using inequalities. And so *yes,* after first defining $(a,b) = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid a<x<b\}$, your definition of an interval is essentially the same as mine.

Comment: I have added a comment to the question which is essentially saying the same thing as your answer. And then I checked your answer. If you wish I can delete my comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use that as a definition since if you think about the kinds of intervals on a case by case basis this covers all the cases.

I don't think there's cause to be critical of your textbook for the informality in referring to $[a,b)$ or $(c, \infty)$ as intervals without such a definition.